# Cannot add DataTables.net javascript to Joomla 1.5

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm having a problem here where I could not run DataTables.net javascripts on Joomla 1.5. The script is as what it is on DataTables

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

To say that it is Joomla stripping off my code, I managed to run Google Chart API javascript without any problems. Any experts here mind sharing why this is happening?

UPDATED:

Below is my code :

```
   <?php

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

    $doc->addScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
    $doc->addScript('http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js');
    $doc->addScriptDeclaration('
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $("#example").DataTable();
        });
    ');

    function listProcess($process,$date_sort)
    {
        $asas= new class_asas;
        $sql = "
        Select proses_pendaftaran.*, secretary.*, 
            kpps_agih.name as kpps_agih_name,
            kpps_sokong.name as kpps_sokong_name,
            ppps.name as ppps_name,
            tps.name as tps_name,
            pjs.name as pjs_name,
            pt.name as pt_name

        From proses_pendaftaran 
            Left join jos_users secretary On secretary.id=proses_pendaftaran.user_id
            Left join jos_users kpps_agih On kpps_agih.id=proses_pendaftaran.kpps_agih_id
            Left join jos_users kpps_sokong On kpps_sokong.id=proses_pendaftaran.kpps_sokong_id
            Left join jos_users ppps On ppps.id=proses_pendaftaran.ppps_semak_id
            Left join jos_users tps On tps.id=proses_pendaftaran.tps_perakui_id
            Left join jos_users pjs On pjs.id=proses_pendaftaran.pjs_lulus_id
            Left join jos_users pt On ppps.id=proses_pendaftaran.pt_rekod_id
        Where current_process='$process' 
        Order By $date_sort DESC";
        //echo $sql;
        return $asas->readAll($sql);


    }
    $userm = $asas->getUser();
    $userid = $user->get('id');
    $userm=$asas->getOtherUser($userid);
    $usergroup = $userm['user_group_id'];

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //PJS, TPS, KPPS
    if($usergroup ==7 or $usergroup ==2 or $usergroup ==3 or $usergroup ==4 or $usergroup ==5)
    {
    $datas=listProcess('ppps_semak','kpps_agih_date');
    ?>
    <h1 class="contentheading">Senarai Permohonan Yang Telah Diagihkan (Menunggu Tindakan PPPS/PPPS(P))</h1>
    <table id ="example" width="100%" class="systemTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th width="20%">NAMA BADAN SUKAN</th>
            <th width="10%">NAMA PEMOHON</th>
            <th width="10%">TARIKH PERMOHONAN</th>
            <th width="10%">PEGAWAI KPPS</th>
            <th width="15%">TARIKH DIAGIHKAN</th>
            <th width="10%">PEGAWAI PPPS</th>
            <th width="10%">STATUS</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
        foreach($datas as $data)
        {

        ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo strtoupper($data['NamaBadan']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo strtoupper($data['name']) ?><br/>[<?php echo $data['TelPejabat'] ?>]</td>
            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data['tarikh_mohon'])) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo strtoupper($data['kpps_agih_name']) ?></t>
            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y (h:ia)',strtotime($data['kpps_agih_date'])) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo strtoupper($data['ppps_name']) ?></t>
            <td><?php echo strtoupper($data['current_process']) ?></t>
        </tr>
        <?php

        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <br/>

    <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to import the scripts and add your custom code:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
$doc->addScript('http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $("#example").DataTable();
    });
');
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tested this myself a couple of minutes ago and it works perfectly for me. Please copy and paste the script (a few changes made) and HTML I have provided.

Comment: Nope it didn't work. I have tried using this method even before I asked this question. But i dont know, it seems something about joomla making datatables js not appearing. I tried running it outside joomla and it ran perfectly. I tried running Google API inside joomla, it ran perfectly too. But not with datatables.net. Puzzled.

Comment: @mfmz - Does your browser console report any errors? Also, where are you adding this code?

Comment: @mfmz - I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: `new class_asas`? Why don't you use Joomla coding standards for your database query? There is nothing wrong with the code I have provided you withg, therefore there must be something wrong with your PHP code. You need to start debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you are in a Joomla environment there will a conflict between mootools and jquery, so you cannot use

```
      $(document).ready( function () { $("#example").DataTable(); });
```

but instead

```
      jQuery.noConflict(); 
      jQuery(document).ready( function () { jQuery("#example").DataTable(); });
```

in other words, you cannot use $ when mootools library is present.

You may also consider using Tabulizer for Joomla (http://www.tabulizer.com) that has all the datatables functionality without the hassle.